# Rails/Ruby equivalent of PHP file_get_contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Would like to know the Rails/Ruby equivalent of the following PHP:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents(URL_GOES_HERE))
```

The URL is an external resource that returns json data (Facebook's API).

I've tried:

```
data = JSON.parse(URL_GOES_HERE)
```

but I assume I still need the `file_get_contents' part? How do I do this in Rails 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
require 'open-uri'

file = open(URL_GOES_HERE)

data = JSON.parse file.read
```

Comment: I think this is right but I am trying to access an attribute within data using `data.attribute` but getting undefined method error. Am I accessing the attribute in the right way?

Comment: got it - it's `data['attribute']`